# Updating Multiple Columns in Table from Another Table in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I am trying to make updates to multiple columns in one table from multiple columns in another table in MS access.

I have two tables set up:

1. `App Disposition` - will be a linked table receiving updates from the 'App Updates' table
2. `App Updates` - table which will be used to import updated information to

I have created 3 queries (Find Added Records, Insert Added Records, Find All Changes) but I am receiving the following error for the 4th query which as an `UPDATE` query to implement the changes which have been found.

I have checked the syntax and am unable to find any reason on why the query is not working.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

**Error:**

> 'Syntax Error in JOIN operation'

**UPDATE query:**

```
UPDATE App Disposition
INNER JOIN App Updates ON [App Updates].AppID = [App Disposition].AppID
SET 
[App Disposition].Decision = [App Updates].[Updated Decision], 
[App Disposition].[App Replacement Name] = [App Updates].DuPont_Replacement_Application, 
[App Disposition].[Replacement App ID] = [App Updates].ReplacementID,
[App Disposition].[What You Need to Do] = [App Updates].[What You Need to Do], 
[App Disposition].[User Friendly Comment], = [App Updates].[User Friendly Comment]
WHERE (
    ([App Disposition].Decision<>[App Updates].[Updated Decision]) OR 
    ([App Disposition].[App Replacement Name]<>[App Updates].DuPont_Replacement_Application) OR
    ([App Disposition].[Replacement App ID]<>[App Updates].ReplacementID) OR
    ([App Disposition].[What You Need to Do]<>[App Updates].[What You Need to Do]) OR
    ([App Disposition].[User Friendly Comment]<>[App Updates].[User Friendly Comment]) OR
    );
```

Comment: You appear to missing the brackets here `UPDATE [App Disposition] INNER JOIN [App Updates]....`  You will find that query writing is so much simpler if you don't use reserved characters/words in your object names.

Comment: There is an OR at end with nothing following.

Answer (score 0):

Your table names contain white spaces, (App Updates) and (App Disposition), *always* avoid it like the plague. Two references are missing [ ]'s.

If can't change names, use [App Updates] and [App Disposition] but consider it as a patch, not as good design.

Answer (score 0):

I spot three typos:

1. You need to surround your table names with square brackets, as they contain spaces, i.e. this:

   ```
   UPDATE App Disposition
   INNER JOIN App Updates
   ```

   Should become:

   ```
   UPDATE [App Disposition]
   INNER JOIN [App Updates]
   ```
2. You have an errant comma here:

   ```sql
   [App Disposition].[User Friendly Comment], = [App Updates].[User Friendly Comment]
             -- This shouldn't be here -----^
   ```
3. You have a trailing `OR` here:

   ```sql
   ([App Disposition].[User Friendly Comment]<>[App Updates].[User Friendly Comment]) OR
                                                -- Nothing follows this final OR -----^
   ```